Parameter Type Error in C based Python Package
At my wits end here, according to my knowledge of Python, and typing I see no reason as to why this is failing.
This is my first time building a python package using C code. I'm well aware I could do this in python natively, and not use C code, but I want to practice C and also have plans for a larger complex package I would like to try someday that this is a test run for.
This is my function, a fuzzy search of a list of dictionaries.
def fuzzydicsearch(list_of_dicts: list[dict], search_key: Optional[str] | None = None, search_value: Optional[str] | None = None)

The list of dicts param must always be included, but the search key and search value should be optional. If both are included, search both, if one is included search that field. The logic I have is sound and works if both are included, or even if I set the param to a string.
The issue is that for some reason, Python will not allow me  to use optional None param. Below is the code from the FuzzyDicSearch.py file which calls the C code I created.
Code:
import os
from ctypes import cdll, c_char_p, POINTER, c_void_p, c_int
import ctypes
import sys
from typing import Optional

# Get the path to the directory containing this module
module_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)

# Determine the extension of the shared library based on the platform
if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
    lib_name = "fuzzydicsearch.dll"
elif sys.platform.startswith('linux') or sys.platform.startswith('darwin'):
    lib_name = "fuzzydicsearch.so"
else:
    raise NotImplementedError("Platform not supported")

# Load the shared library (your compiled C code) from the module directory
lib_path = os.path.join(module_dir, lib_name)
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary(lib_path)

# Define the function signature for the fuzzy_search function in your C code
fuzzy_search = lib.fuzzydicsearch
fuzzy_search.argtypes = [POINTER(c_void_p), c_char_p, c_char_p, c_int]
fuzzy_search.restype = POINTER(c_void_p)

def convert_result(result_ptr):
    # Create an empty list to store the dictionaries
    result = []
    
    # Define the C struct for the dictionary (assuming it's a simple key-value pair)
    class DictStruct(ctypes.Structure):
        _fields_ = [("key", ctypes.c_char_p),
                    ("value", ctypes.c_char_p)]
    
    # Get the number of elements in the result array (assuming it's terminated with a NULL pointer)
    num_elements = 0
    while result_ptr[num_elements]:
        num_elements += 1
    
    # Iterate over each element in the result array
    for i in range(num_elements):
        # Get the pointer to the current element
        current_ptr = result_ptr[i]
        
        # Convert the C struct pointer to a Python dictionary
        current_dict = {
            "key": current_ptr.contents.key.decode(),  # Assuming keys and values are C strings
            "value": current_ptr.contents.value.decode()
        }
        
        # Append the dictionary to the result list
        result.append(current_dict)
    
    return result

def fuzzydicsearch(list_of_dicts: list[dict], search_key: Optional[str] = None, search_value: Optional[str] = None):
    # Convert None to NULL pointer for C function
    c_search_key = ctypes.c_char_p(search_key.encode('utf-8')) if search_key else ctypes.c_char_p(None)
    c_search_value = ctypes.c_char_p(search_value.encode('utf-8')) if search_value else ctypes.c_char_p(None)
    
    dict_array = (ctypes.c_void_p * len(list_of_dicts))()
    for i, d in enumerate(list_of_dicts):
        dict_array[i] = ctypes.c_void_p(id(d))
    
    results_ptr = fuzzy_search(dict_array, c_search_key, c_search_value, len(list_of_dicts))
    
    results = convert_result(results_ptr)
    
    return results

This is the error I am getting calling the function:
results = fuzzydicsearch(dicts, None, keyword)
TypeError: argument 2 must be str, not None

I have the same parameters and values in the init function for the package. As noted calling them with the params of an empty string instead of None works, I am just not certain as to why it is raising this error.
Please if anyone has any suggestions on how to fix this it would be great.
I will most likely be refactoring most of my code to break this out and type check earlier in the code but at this point I really just want an answer for my own sanity as I cannot find a reason as to why this happens.

Optional[str] | None looks weird.  Optional[str] should be sufficient by itself. See How should I use the Optional type hint?

This looks like strictly a Python-side issue.  Is the [c] tag actually relevant here?

Why not pass an empty string as default?

Would you please present the stack trace for your TypeError? The c_char_p type doesn't accept strings anyway (it requires bytes, instead) so it's unclear to me where that error is actually coming from.

On the other hand, c_char_p indeed is not documented to accept None.  Have you tried ctypes.cast(ctypes.c_void_p(), ctypes.c_char_p) in place of ctypes.c_char_p(None)?

Or for that matter, just ctypes.c_void_p() might work.  On the C side, void * is assignable to char * without a cast, and the two types are required to have the same size and representation, but I don't know whether ctypes provides analogous behavior in that regard.
